# UIImagePickerController when dismissed pushes view to 20 px up in iOS 6.0 only

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

**EDIT** : I am using `UIStoryBoard`.

I have `presented` like this:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePicker.delegate = self;

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; //| UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum ;
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage,nil];

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{

        }];  
    }
}
```

Now when `dissmissed`

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSLog(@"Image : %@",image);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```

Now `view` becomes like this as shown in `fiqure` :

[image]

**EDIT** : view gets pushed up to 20px when dissmissed.

**EDIT** : This is only in iOS 6.0 only

Comment: Did you have tabbar in this screen? or Are you setting view frame anywhere? because same code i also run in my app its working fine.

Comment: yes i am setting [self.navigationController.view setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]; in viewDidLoad method

Comment: Is that blue part a UIView or Navigation bar ?

Comment: yes its UIImageView !!!!!!!

Comment: i was facing these issue in iOS 6 only and iOS 7.0 was not in seen yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was i was **setting frame** of `view controller` which is in `protrait mode` as its `previous view` was in `landscape mode`.

```
self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,...,...);
```

Whenever `imagepicker` `dissmiss` got `called` it `moved` to `original position` as `mentioned`.

Now changed in `structure` for `orientation` **without setting self.view frame externally** `solved` my `problem`.

Answer (score 0):

If that blue part of view is custom `UIView` then you should check the auto resizing mask for that view. You will find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, and in my case 20 pixels was the status bar height.
So, try to set status bar visibility to NO before showing imagePicker and YES when it finished (in delegate methods).

something like this:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{
        }];


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   // ... your code here
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on iOS 8.2. After picking video using UIImagePickerController the frame is increased by 20px, top area of view controller is looking good, but the bottom is cut off.
The solution is:

```
-(void)openPicker {}
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    //configure image picker here
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(showStatusBar) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)showStatusBar {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    });
}
```